# Modifying .htaccess rewrite rule for MVC application

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is the rewrite rule I currently use for my MVC application:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?$ application/controller/$1.php?method=$2&param=$4
```

Displays as: www.website.com/controller/method/param

The param URI is optional. How would I make method optional as well, so it will allow the user to go to www.website.com/controller?

Could I also additionally force the url to have a trailing slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|) application/controller/$1.php?method=$2&param=$3 [L]
```

The `(?:/([^/]+)|)` are optional capture groups that allows for a "nothing" using the `|` symbol.